# why this iteration happens between every 2 club name

Tags: mysql

ok i have this  query from (Mr.Austin):

```
SELECT
  IF(is_real, '**ANY WORD**', full_name) AS full_name,
  IF(is_real, '', club_name) AS club_name
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      full_name,
      club_name,
      (@row_num2:= @row_num2 + 1) AS row_num
    FROM
      (
        SELECT p3.*
        FROM
          (
        SELECT
          p2.*,
          (@row_num := @row_num + 1) AS row_num
        FROM
          (
            SELECT *
            FROM players AS p1
            WHERE y_of_birth = 2000
          ) AS p2
        CROSS JOIN
          (
            SELECT
              @row_num := 0,
              @count := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM players WHERE y_of_birth = 2000)
          ) AS vars
        ORDER BY club_name
      ) AS p3
    ORDER BY row_num % FLOOR(@row_num / 2), row_num
  ) AS p4
CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      @row_num2 := -1,
      @extra := GREATEST(2, POW(2, CEIL(LOG2(@count)))) - @count) AS vars
  ) AS data
LEFT JOIN
  (
    (SELECT 1 AS is_real)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT 0 AS is_real)
  ) AS filler
ON
  MOD(row_num, FLOOR(@count / @extra)) = 0 AND
  row_num / FLOOR(@count / @extra) < @extra
ORDER BY row_num, is_real
```

it works well and there are no adjacency between two similar club_name but the problem is when i have large result of query for example 214 player it gave me many iterative between the same different club_name for example `El-ahly` vs `Ismaily` then again `El-ahly` vs `Ismaily` then again `El-ahly` vs `Ismaily` then repeat again with `wadi dgla` vs `Cocorico` then again `wadi dgla` vs `Cocorico` then again `wadi dgla` vs `Cocorico` why this iteration happened and how can i fix this problem ? can i make this iteration happens is there anyway to solve this problem to be one or two maximum times the native query of no adjacency between two similar club name is from (Mr.Gordon Linoff):

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = club_name, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := club_name, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from players p cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @c := '') params
      order by club_name
     ) p join
     (select club_name, count(*) as cnt
      from players p
      group by club_name
     ) pc
     on p.club_name = pc.club_name
order by rn * (@rn / cnt);
```

**sqlfiddle:**

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e229b/1)

Comment: so to be clear, from your [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e229b/1), it is the adjacency of id's 11 and 10 (Ismaily) we are focusing on? and your question addresses how you would rather have it?

Comment: i get different ordering depending on what server it is run on, and also whether or not `DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1` is remmed out

Comment: the tip off on charset was that the query choked when run in mysql command line, but worked fine in Workbench. regardless, no results are the same. so even to propose something might be fruitless

Comment: @DrewPierce there are no adjacency between any two similar club_names to above but the problem is look at id `14`,`13` again iterated with the same `18`,`10` and with `1`,`15` again iterated `12` ,`2` that is the problem iterating many times with the same two club_names .

Comment: i know. i just can't get any two systems to return the same ordering. i will keep looking

Comment: [Here](http://pastie.org/10314363) is my pastie output of your fiddle with my doing exactly what you did ... that is no change to charset. that is thru Workbench. Were I to run your query in mysql command line, it explodes complaining about swedish this yada yada that

Comment: @DrewPierce but why the adjacency between `11,10` why this happened

Comment: until we can eliminate the charset issue i don't know what to say

Comment: ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (cp850_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: @DrewPierce i greatly appreciate your efforts but the collation im using utf8_general_ci .

Comment: **1)** My pastie from exactly your fiddle doesn't match your fiddle result set. **2)** The query blows up with error 1267 outside of workbench

Comment: @DrewPierce so the result can be different between mysql versions too ? im worry now :(.

Comment: if i create table with this `ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 default charset utf8 default collate utf8_general_ci;` then i am able to run queries in mysql command line (but the results are different than your fiddle). But at least no adjacency . If i create a new SQL Fiddle with same collation, results are different

Comment: @DrewPierce but the iteration with same two club_names still exist in both isn't it ha ?

Comment: i think the issue is, hey I want XXX and XXX not to stack on top of each other, (Gordon delivered that) and I want to minimize XXX and YYY stacking on top of each other too frequently. correct ?

Comment: so maybe that is best handled in a powerful programming language after the fact, as opposed to mysql, t-sql, pl, etc being all things to all people :>

Comment: @DrewPierce yeah but without any iteration between every two difference club_names .. about php or any programming language how can i make that with mysql array the problem is when i have tried many times with inject any `non existent word` it via php it gave me the result in last place in the table for example : all `club_names` with `full_names` the that produced from database then put all php arrays that i added the problem is i can't combined mysqlarray with php array `**AnY WORD**` with the same result to be able to play with php programming language thats it .

Comment: ok trying to digest that. but would you agree with this statement. `I like Gordon's and Mr. Austin's output, but hey, PHP programmers out there, can we mix it up a little better so XXX and YYY don't occur adjacent as much as they do?` Because right now you are standing on 3rd base. We are trying to bring you home